# A realization of a Poisson Point Process on $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I am trying to visualize a 2 D homogenous PPP by plotting the realization in MATLAB.

I want to plot points over the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane in MATLAB, a 2D Homogenous Poisson Point Process PPP is defined by its intensity

$$ \Phi_1 \text{ with intensity } \lambda_1  $$

For example lets take  $$\lambda_1 = (80^2\pi)^{-1}$$

I appreciate any advice.

**Edit based on answer below**

```
   L1=10 ;
   L2=10;
intensity=(80^2*pi)^(-1);
parameter=L1*L2*intensity;
N=poissrnd(parameter,1,1);
x=unifrnd(1,10,1,N);
y=unifrnd(1,10,1,N)
```

Problem is that $N$ is zero ? Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To visualize this on a finite display, you will need to restrict to a rectangle $R$, say  $[x_1, x_2] \times [y_1, y_2]$. The number of points $N$ in the PPP contained in $R$ is a Poisson random variable, where the mean is $\mu = \text{Area}(R)\cdot \lambda_1$. In MATLAB you can simulate a Poisson random variable using the `poissrnd` function. Once you have simulated a value for $N$, you then simply simulate $N$ independent random points in $R$, the x and y coordinates each having a uniform distribution.

Comment: so step 1) find area of region 2) number of points is poisson variables with parameter $\lambda*\mu$ 3) find a realization of $N$ 4) generate that many points ...is step 3 correct? @Brent Kerby

Comment: You can simulate each of the coordinates using the function `unifrnd`.

Comment: Can you check my comment? I wrote above? in particular do I have to fix a realization of $N$?

Comment: Yes, that sums it up, except the parameter of the Poisson should be the area times the intensity.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to fix a realization of $N$ right? @Brent Kerby

Comment: Yes, to get one realization of the PPP, you just need to fix one realization of the Poisson random variable $N$.

Comment: I will provide a code in  my question, can you please check if its correct? @Brent Kerby

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21393/discussion-between-brent-kerby-and-henry).